# Unzip files in subdirectories bash

Tags: bash, gunzip

I have a directory called `test1` which contains multiple directories. In each directory `test1/*/`, there is a `*.gz` file that I want to unzip. I tried writing this code but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

```
for folder in test1/*/; do find . -name "*.gz" | while read filename; do gunzip -d $filename;done ;done
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
gunzip test1/*/*.gz
```

`gunzip` will extract the file in the directory it is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that using `find`:

```
cd test1
find . -name "*.gz" -execdir tar xzf '{}' \;
```

Remember that `unzip` command only works with `.zip` files.

**PS:** If `.gz` files have not been created using `tar czf` then use `gunzip` instead:

```
find . -name "*.gz" -execdir gunzip '{}' \;
```

Comment: Actually it depends on how `.gz` files have been created. One can always do `tar czf file.gz *.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I edited my command and it works now:

```
find ${path} -name "*.gz" | while read filename; do gunzip -d $filename; done
```